# Join in Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have two tables in Firebase, users and comments.
I display comments in Activity with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, and whene I display it, I would like to get username of user who posted this comment

```
 {
  "comments" : {
    "-L0hqpk1BGX36jNvaA-h" : {
      "comment" : "Hello"
      "date_post" : 1513671580718,
      "user_id" : "ksRMjacofzZDX1ir0m9iB2HWUhV2"
      }
  },
  "users" : {
      "ksRMjacofzZDX1ir0m9iB2HWUhV2" : {
        "username" : "user1"
      }
  }
 }
```

Is there a good way to get username of this person when I use FirebaseRecyclerView ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you add the username also with the comments table, then I guess it'll be very easy to query it and show it. Now the reason why i'm saying this is that Firebase is unlike SQL and denormalization is normal is firebase.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I will make your proposal instead of making another request on the users table.

Answer (score 1):

Das is right. You should probably add the username to the comments table. That way you don't have to download the user's profile just to get the username. However, if you really do want to get the username through their profile, it's quite easy since you already have their id. Just do this:

```
//Get the user id when you retrieve the comment

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference.child("users").child(userid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            String username = user.getUsername();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I have do this in populateViewHolder, but I'm looking if there is a better solution to do what I explained.